# Should Tabs controlled with JavaScript have different URLS?

Tags: javascript, html, url, onclick, seo

On a few of my websites I have tabs that when clicked displays and hides content for the user to flick between with ease. I know using JavaScript you can fake a URL for Google tracking purposes. But for a marketing/Google indexing point of view should the users click on these tabs and be presented with a new URL after a page load?

My thought is JavaScript show/hide option is better for usability and the customers journey, especially on mobiles. However, the worry would be these tabs affecting the site from a marketing/SEO perspective.

P.S. all the content is currently on the page, JavaScript just hides and shows this information meaning when Google crawls the website it can see the information.

Thanks

Comment: Most common practice for bookmarking purposes is to use anchor hash and let the url update hash on tab activation and conversely activate the correct tab on page load if hash is present

Comment: new url would only help if you wanted to reload page each time a tab is clicked

Comment: @charlietfl So not different URLs just hashed to allow users to bookmark. But what about Google, our marketing team are worried about the lose of extra links/URLs on Google?